# Translating VB.NET LINQ Query with Sum to C# LINQ Query

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

i have a LINQ Query which is written in VB.NET:

```
foo = (From p In lOrder 
       Group By p.ItemCode Into Group = Sum(p.Quantity)
      ).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.ItemCode, Function(x) x.Group)
```

My problem is to translate the Sum. C# seems to not like it very well.

Can anybody help me translating this query?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an exact translation of your LINQ query in C#:

```
var foo = lOrder.GroupBy(p => p.ItemCode, 
                           (key, values) => new 
                           {
                               ItemCode = key, 
                               Group = values.Sum(v => v.Quantity)
                           })
                .ToDictionary(x => x.ItemCode, x => x.Group);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get a mapping between the item code to the cumulative quantity of the items under this code.

Given an IEnumerable named orders you can do the following:

```
  var foo = from p in orders
  group p by p.ItemCode into OrderGroupedByCode
  select new { Code = OrderGroupedByCode.Key, Sum = OrderGroupedByCode.Sum(x => x.Quentity) };
```

This gives you an IEnumerable of anonymous objects the you can easily turn into a dictionaryif you want:

```
foo.ToDictionary(x => x.Code, x => x.Sum)
```